# Prove that $\operatorname{Im} ((T'))^0 \subseteq \phi(\operatorname{Ker}(T))$ where $\phi$ is the canonical isomorphism from $V \to V''$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$. Let $T : V \to W$ be linear. Prove that $\operatorname{Im} ((T'))^0 \subseteq \phi(\operatorname{Ker}(T))$, where $\phi$ is the canonical isomorphism from $V \to V''$ and $T'$ is the adjoint of $T$.

Any idea on how to proceed here? Many thanks!

Comment: You need to prove that if $h\in V''$ satisfies $h(T'(\nu))$ for all $\nu\in W'$, then $T(\phi^{-1}h)=0$...

Comment: I presume "$h$ satisfies $h(T'(\nu))$ for all $\nu\in W'$" should be the meaning of $h\in\operatorname{Im}((T'))^0$. Is it not?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... I thought what you meant was $h(T'(\nu))= 0$. $X^0$ denotes the annihilator of a space $X$, for me.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, sorry about that. I wrote it twice without realising it.

Comment: I see :) . Nonetheless you reminded me that $\phi$ is of course a bijection and so I can take preimages. This makes the problem alot easier! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v \in V$ such that $\phi(v) \in (\operatorname{im} T')^0$, that is, $\operatorname{im}T' \subseteq \ker\phi(v)$. Then, for any $f \in W'$ we have
$$f(T(v)) = T'(f)(v) = \phi(v)(T'(f)) = 0 \tag{$*$}$$
meaning that$^1$ $T(v) = 0_W$. So, we are started with $v \in \phi^{-1}((\operatorname{im} T')^0)$ and we are showed that $v \in \ker T$; thus $\phi^{-1}((\operatorname{im} T')^0) \subseteq \ker T$ and then$^2$ $$(\operatorname{im} T')^0 = \phi(\phi^{-1}((\operatorname{im} T')^0)) \subseteq \phi(\ker T).$$

---

$^1$ If $T(v) \neq 0_W$, then (since $W$ is finite dimensional) we can choose a basis $\beta$ of $W$ whose first element is $T(v)$, and then define $f : W \to F$ by $f(T(v)) = 1$, $f(w) = 0$ for every $w \in \beta \setminus \{T(v)\}$, and extend it by linearity. This contradicts $(*)$.

$^2$ Here is where I used that $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Very helpful. I understand everything perfectly except for your second footnote. I don't see why it is necessary that $V$ is finite dimensional for the inclusion to follow. If you have time, could you please elaborate? Many thanks!

Comment: Your welcome! Sure, it is always true that $\phi(\phi^{-1}(S)) \subseteq S$, but the equality occurs only when $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: Perfect. You have solved my problem! Thanks.